# Are "sample curve" and "simulation zones" nodes incompatible?

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I'm trying to sample a curve in the new simulation node, but without any result...

I attached 2 screenshots, one of a functioning node setup and one a that doesn't work. I would like the second setup to work, as it allows getting more information in the simulation zone.

Are the simulation nodes and the curve sample node not yet compatible or I'm I missing something?

Best regards.

---

Sorry for the lacking details. Here are the 2 screenshots I mentioned before.

I also attached a WeTransfer link: [.blendfile](https://we.tl/t-i2PNtqhPKU). The file uses version 3.6. As you can see in the file, the "Working Setup" geometry nodes allows the sphere to follow the curve when playing the animation. This is not the case in the "Not working setup" and I can't understand why.

Thanks for the answers!

Best regards.

[image: Working setup][image: Not working setup]

Comment: unfortunately there is no screenshot...and a blend file would be perfect

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your project works for me in 3.6β https://i.imgur.com/y1r4Vd8.gif

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about unreleased version that is still in development.

Comment: Markus, are both geometry node setups working for you?